# Json data bind div in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Please help. I am new at angularjs, I want to bind json data into div as list using angularjs

Sample Data

```
"[{"T_FORM_CODE":"T12040"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"T18025"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"Q12014"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"R12039"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Json Data :

```
    const HEROES = [
    {"T_FORM_CODE":"T12040"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"T18025"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"Q12014"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"R12039"}
];
```

Template :

```
  <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
                    <td>{{hero.T_FORM_CODE}}</td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
             <tr ng-repeat="x in array">
                 <td>{{x.T_FORM_CODE}}</td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.array = [{"T_FORM_CODE":"T12040"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"T18025"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"Q12014"},{"T_FORM_CODE":"R12039"}];
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-repeat.
you can see plunker

```
 <div ng-repeat ="dr in data">
 {{dr.column}}
 </div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0q9sqyc9KKTtdZJIPH7O?p=preview)